# confusion over static final method accessed by multiple threads at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I am wondering ,Can 2 different threads can call a final static method at the same time?
Does  a static final method  become synchronized?
Thanks in advance.
BR
Gaurav

Answer (score 1):

Many threads can call a final static method at the same time (actually any static method at the same time, `final` indicates the method may not be overriden). No, it is not inherently synchronized but it does have local variables. You can always print the current thread id if you want to see what threads are where like

```
static final void printThreadId() {
    Thread ct = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.printf("%d %s%n", ct.getId(), ct.getName());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printThreadId();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            printThreadId();
            Thread.yield();
            printThreadId();
        }
    };
    Thread[] arr = { new Thread(r), new Thread(r) };
    for (Thread th : arr) {
        th.start();
    }
    Thread.yield();
    printThreadId();
    for (Thread th : arr) {
        try {
            th.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Example output

```
1 main
1 main
10 Thread-1
9 Thread-0
10 Thread-1
9 Thread-0
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can 2 different threads can call a final static method at the same time?

Yes.

> Does a static final method become synchronized?

No. Only a `synchronized` method becomes synchronized, or one that uses `synchronized` internally.

Answer (score 0):

**Can 2 different threads can call a final static method at the same time?**

Yes , 2 different threads can call a final static method at the same time.

**Does a static final method become synchronized ?**

You can make the method synchronized explicitly but that will be class level synchronization not the object level. Yo need to use *Synchronized* keyword for this.

Comment: Hi All, Thank you so much for your valueable response's. Cheers.Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

1. Of course you can. Just take care when writing to any `static` field. Remember that `int` *is* atomic in Java, but a `double` or a `long` are not necessarily atomic.
2. You don't get the function level synchronisation on a static method since there's no object to synchronise on. But you can synchronise on an object (perhaps even a static field) in that function.

Comment: 2. But you do get the *class*-level synchronization.